# Winforms DateTimePicker - distinguishing between how date was selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have some requirements in how a DateTimePicker selects a date: it basically needs to close it's parent form when a date is selected.  I was originally thinking I could just use the ValueChanged event to basically capture that and close the form; however, this doesn't work because using the arrow keys for navigation is firing a value changed every time.

What I need is either:
a.) if the user hits ENTER after using arrow keys to select a date or
or
b.) if the user clicks on a date
occurs, it should close the form.

My first thought was to ditch trying to use the ValueChanged event handler and instead use the CloseUp handler, but this doesn't work because CloseUp gets fired if the user clicks anywhere around (or behind) the form.

Click events on dates do not seem to work either; and it seems like I can only rely on ValueChanged (somehow).

Is this doable?  Or are the strict requirements preventing this from being possible.

Comment: Why not set a boolean on the DateTimePicker's key down event that says "**this has been typed in**"? This can be checked on the ValueChanged event so that you don't close if someone has typed

Comment: How is this best achieved within the ValueChanged event?

Comment: Not sure I would want you to close a parent form because I clicked on a date.  What if I accidentally clicked on the wrong date or clicked on a date to help navigate in the date time picker.  Making me re-open the form is a tough result for my mistake. This might be a better question for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: @cdkMoose while I agree with you I am trying to match legacy functionality - it is easy (if this occurs) for them to go back into the date picker (form) and re-select.  I need to assume that it is not possible to change this requirement (despite its flaws)

Comment: On the keydown even of the DateTime picker you can set a field variable such as `isTyping` which you would set to true, and then in the ValueChanged you would say `if(!isTyping) this.Close();`. This also means that you can (on the keydown event) say that if the pressed key is enter, it can close the form too

Comment: The parent form is shown as modal or normal? If modally (`ShowDialog`) then set its `AcceptButton` property. And the button from this property set to `DialogResult.OK`. Then the form will close automatically when you press <Enter>.

Comment: @Mani5556, understand the whole legacy thing :) I think you are going to find a number of these dependency blockers that you have already found.     I don't think those events (ValueChanged, etc.) were geared towards form level actions, more towards validation and cross field interaction.

Comment: I ended up ditching the entire idea and using an entirely different component.  Thanks for the suggestions all.